# SmallArraySlide constructor

Tags: javascript, beginner, array

I'm learning to do some small programs in JavaScript and I did some sort of `arraySlider` (I don't really know how to call it). I would like to have some feedback to improve it (more than the code itself, what I should use to make my code better in general).

```
function arrSlider (arr,changeBy) {
    if(!Array.isArray(arr) || isNaN(parseFloat(changeBy)) && !isFinite(changeBy)){ //check if the arguments are correct
        throw 'The first argument have to be an Array and the second one a number';
    };


    this.showDebug = false, //If its true, the debug function will be called after every change
    this.changeBy = changeBy || 3, //The current interval btwn slides
    this.max = arr.length, //The initialArray length
    this.showControl = this.max > this.changeBy ? true : false, //If the array is higher then the interval
    this.initialArray = arr, //The current data stored
    this.current = [], //The current data that will be return
    this.currentIndex = [], //The index of the current in the initialArray
    this.restart = function(arr){
        //Define the initial values
        this.initialArray = arr,
        this.max = arr.length,
        this.changeBy = changeBy || this.changeBy,
        this.showControl = this.max > this.changeBy ? true : false;

        if(this.max >= this.changeBy){  //if the Initial array is higher than the interval, will create the first slide
            let currentIndex = [],
                currentList = arr.filter((val,index) => {if (index <= (this.changeBy-1)){ currentIndex.push(index)} return index <= (this.changeBy-1)});
            this.updateCurrent(currentList,currentIndex);
        } else { //if not, will return the initial array
            this.updateCurrent(arr,arr.map((val,index)=>{ return index}));
        }

        if(this.showDebug){this.debug()}; // debug function will be called if enabled
    },
    this.start = function(){
        if(this.max >= this.changeBy){ //if the Initial array is higher than the interval, will create the first slide
            let currentIndex = [],
                currentList = this.initialArray.filter((val,index) => {if (index <= (this.changeBy-1)){ currentIndex.push(index)} return index <= (this.changeBy-1)});
            this.updateCurrent(currentList,currentIndex);
        } else { //if not, will return the initial array
            this.updateCurrent(this.initialArray,this.initialArray.map((val,index)=>{ return index}));
        }

        if(this.showDebug){this.debug()}; // debug function will be called if enabled
    }
    this.updateArray = function(arr){ //change the initial array and update the showControl
        if(Array.isArray(arr)){ //check if the input is an array
            this.restart(arr);
            this.showControl = this.max > this.changeBy ? true : false;
        } else {
            throw false;
        }
    },
    this.updateInterval = function(value){  //change the interval and update the showControl
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)){ //check if the value its a number
            this.changeBy = value;
            this.showControl = this.max > this.changeBy ? true : false;
        } else {
            throw false;
        }

    },
    this.updateCurrent = function(currentList,currentIndex){ //update the current array 
        this.current = currentList;
        this.currentIndex = currentIndex;
    },
    this.next = function(){ //slides the current array to the next stage
        if(!this.showControl){ //if the interval is smaller than the initial Array, throw and error
            throw false;
        }
        let arr = this.initialArray;
        for(let i in this.current){
            this.currentIndex[i] += this.changeBy;
            if(this.currentIndex[i] >= this.max){
                this.currentIndex[i] -= this.max;
            }
            this.current[i] =  arr[this.currentIndex[i]];
        }

        if(this.showDebug){this.debug()}; // debug function will be called if enabled
    },
    this.back = function(){ //slides the current array to the previous stage
        if(!this.showControl){ //if the interval is smaller than the initial Array, throw and error
            throw false;
        }
        let arr = this.initialArray;
        for(let i in this.current){
            this.currentIndex[i] -= this.changeBy;
            if(this.currentIndex[i] < 0){
                this.currentIndex[i] += this.max;
            }
            this.current[i] =  arr[this.currentIndex[i]];
        }

        if(this.showDebug){this.debug()}; // debug function will be called if enabled
    },
    this.show = function(){ // return the current slide
        return this.current;
    },
    this.help = function(){ //show some help
        console.log(' %cobj.updateArray([array])','color:blue', 'will change the initialArray to the new one.'); 
        console.log(' %cobj.updateInterval(number)','color:blue', 'will change the interval. ');
        console.log(' %cobj.next()','color:blue', 'slides the current array to the next stage. ');
        console.log(' %cobj.back()','color:blue', 'slides the current array to the previous stage ');
        console.log(' %cobj.show()','color:blue', 'return the current slide. ');
        console.log(' %cobj.help()','color:blue', 'show this text. ');
        console.log(' %cobj.showDebug = "true or false"','color:blue', 'to show information on every change');
        console.log(' %cobj.debug()','color:blue', 'show debug information');
    },
    this.debug = function(){ //debug info

            console.log(` Current interval: ${this.changeBy} \n Original array: ${this.initialArray} \n Current array of values: ${this.current} \n Current index of array:  ${this.currentIndex} \n Showcontrol ${this.showControl}`);




    };
    this.start();

}
```

To help you understand what the code does, here is a small example:

```
let example = new arrSlider([1,2,3,4],3); // create the element
```

`example.show()` will return

```
[1,2,3]
```

`example.next()` will change the value to

```
[4,1,2]
```

`example.back()` will change the value to

```
[1,2,3]
```

`example.updateArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` will change the initial value to

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and will set the slide to

```
[1,2,3]
```

`example.updateInterval(5)` will change the interval value to 5, so the slide will return

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and the `example.next()`will change again to

```
[6,7,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general term would be to call it a "window", i.e. the part/slice/subarray you pull out is what is seen through a window of a certain size.

For the code: My initial impression is that there's just too much code here. There are two main tasks:

1. get a n-element slice of an array beginning at a given offset, wrapping around as necessary
2. move the offset back and forth n steps, also wrapping around as necessary

You also have some methods to change the offset and/or array and/or window size, but these I find more or less unnecessary. The instance basically consists of an array, an offset, and a window size. If you want to change all of them, you'd be better off simply making a new instance instead.

You also have `help` and `debug` functions which to my mind don't belong in the object. The `help` contents should be code comments, not console output, and the `debug` method can be removed; just `console.log` the instance instead. Keep the object simple and focussed, don't burden it with incidental concerns.

In terms of style, you're creating a blank object, and adding instance methods to it with `this.someFunction = ...` in the constructor. You should instead define the methods as prototype methods. Defining instance methods in the constructor is useful if the methods need to access local variables as closures. But that's not the case here.

Also, since `arrSlider` is a constructor, JavaScript convention dictates that it should be `PascalCase`: `ArrSlider`.

Here's a much simplified alternative, with the same basic core: Moving the window back and forth over an array.

```
// define the constructor
function WindowedArray(size, array) {
  this.array = array;
  this.offset = 0;
  this.size = size;
}

// define the prototype methods
WindowedArray.prototype = {
  current: function () {
    var slice = [];
    for (var i = this.offset, l = this.offset + this.size; i < l; i++) {
      slice.push(this.array[i % this.array.length]);
    }
    return slice;
  },

  next: function () {
    this.offset = (this.offset + this.size) % this.array.length;
  },

  prev: function () {
    this.offset -= this.size;
    if (this.offset < 0) {
      this.offset = this.array.length + (this.offset % this.array.length);
    }
  }
};
```

The major trick is the use of use the modulo operator (`%`) to make values wrap around the length of the array.

It's just a sketch, with plenty of stuff left as an exercise to the reader. E.g. I've skipped validating input here, but some things certainly should be checked (like if the array's empty, things get weird).

Comment: Thanks =) i'll try to make the code more simple using this method and will also add validating!
A small question if you don't mind, should i use always prototype in my constructors then?

Comment: @ithan Glad you found it useful! As for validating, definitely add some here and there, but don't overdo it either. At some point, you have to just say "Garbage in, garbage out". I.e. you can end up spending a lot of time and code enforcing all sorts of things, or simply say that if someone tries something completely non-sensical, then it's easier to just let things fail